# Converting multiple same name into one single name in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, laravel-5

### This is controller part

```
$users_list = User::where('id', '>', 4)
                ->where('status', 1)
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->get();

$companys = WorkFor::all();
$categories = TaskCetagorys::all();
//$report_table = array();

foreach($users_list as $user){

  $report_table = array();

  $user_tasks = Task::select('task_date',DB::raw('group_concat(tasks.workfor_name) as workfor_name'),'taskcategory_name',DB::raw('group_concat(tasks.description SEPARATOR ",,,") as description'))
                       ->wherebetween('task_date', array("$start_task_date", "$end_task_date"))
                            ->where('asign_id', '=', $user->id)
                            ->where('status', 1)
                            ->groupBy('workfor_id')
                            ->orderBy('task_date')
                            ->get();
 }
```

### This is my view part

```
 <table id = "datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered"  style="font-size: 85%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="bg-primary col-sm-2" >
                            <font size="4">
                                Employee
                            </font>
                        </th>
                        {{--<th class="bg-danger">--}}
                            {{--<font size="4">--}}
                                {{--Company--}}
                            {{--</font>--}}
                        {{--</th>--}}
                        {{--<th class="bg-success">--}}
                            {{--<font size="4">--}}
                               {{--Category--}}
                            {{--</font>--}}
                        {{--</th>--}}
                        {{--<th class="bg-warning">--}}
                            {{--<font size="4">--}}
                                {{--Task--}}
                            {{--</font>--}}
                        {{--</th>--}}
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach ($report_table_all as $report)
                        <?php
                        $name = $report[0]['user_name'];
                        $user_designation = $report[0]['user_designation'];
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{--<font size="2">--}}
                                <strong>{{$name}}</strong></br>
                                {{--</font>--}}
                                <font size="1">
                                    {{$user_designation}}
                                </font>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @foreach ( $report as $daily_report )

                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable" style="font-size: 85%">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr class="primary" style="font-size: 15px;">

                                            <th class="bg-info">Concern</th>
                                            <th class="bg-warning">Category</th>
                                            <th class="bg-success">Task</th>
                                            <th class="bg-danger">Date</th>

                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <?php
                                        $total = 0;
                                        $sn = 1;
                                        $sn_total = '*';
                                        ?>
                                        @foreach($daily_report['user_task_lists'] as $user_task)
                                            <tr>


                                                <td style="background-color: rgba(227, 255, 140, 0.98); ">
                                                    <center>{{$user_task->workfor_name}}</center>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable" style="font-size: 85%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-size: 13px;background-color: rgba(19, 214, 255, 0.98)">
                                                                {{$sn}}.{{ $user_task->taskcategory_name }}
                                                                <?php $sn += floatval(1) ?>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 12px;">
                                                    {{ $user_task->description}}

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{date('d-M-Y',strtotime($user_task->task_date))}}
                                                </td>


                                            </tr>

                                        @endforeach

                                    </table>

                            </td>

                            @endforeach




                        </tr>

                    @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I am using **laravel 5.2** version.in my **controller** i fetch one column data using **group_concat** function.When i showing these data using **view**,the same name repeats many times in a row.but i want to show these repeated data only one time.for example,i fetched my **workfor_name** from database using group_concat.then when i showimg them the **workfor_name** repeats many times as PALO,PALO,PALO,PALO,PALO,PALO,PALO,PALO,PALO in a row.i want only one PALO in my row.need help.!!!

[this is my view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWz7A.jpg)

Comment: Show us some code, that will help us to diagonise

Comment: post updated @Thamilan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the keyword `DISTINCT` to your `GROUP_CONCAT` call.

```
$user_tasks = Task::select('task_date',DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT tasks.workfor_name) as workfor_name'),'taskcategory_name',DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT tasks.description SEPARATOR ",,,") as description'))
                   ->wherebetween('task_date', array("$start_task_date", "$end_task_date"))
                        ->where('asign_id', '=', $user->id)
                        ->where('status', 1)
                        ->groupBy('workfor_id')
                        ->orderBy('task_date')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: #Rob bro.can you give me suggestion about how to separate group_concat data by new line?i tried but couldn't find a way to handle it.!!need some help.

Comment: Something like {{ str_replace(',', '<br>', $user_task->workfor_name) }} should work

Comment: Correction, {!! str_replace(',', '<br>', $user_task->workfor_name) !!}, because you're outputting HTML.